# Updating totalRows in pager after ajaxProcessing

Tags: tablesorter

I am building my table using tablesorter with external ajaxProcessing call.

My pager output shows filteredRows and totalRows

```
.tablesorterPager({

    output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} filtered ({totalRows} total)  ',
    ajaxUrl:"{% url 'stats_json' %}{page}?{filterList:filter}&{sortList:column}&pagesize={size}",

}
```

I am returning the table rows and number of filtered rows in `ajaxProcessing`:

```
ajaxProcessing: function(data){                 
    var rows=[];
    ....
    rows.push(row);
    return [data.filtered_rows_no,rows];
}
```

After filtering, my `filteredRows` is always the same as `totalRows` number but they should be different.

How should I update `totalRows`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When returning extra values from within the `ajaxProcessing` function don't return an array. Instead, return an object containing the total, filtered rows and any extra values as follows ([ref](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#object)):

```
return {
  total: data.total_rows_no,
  filteredRows: data.filtered_rows_no,
  rows: rows // array of arrays
};
```

For the `total`, I am guessing that the value is contained in `data.total_rows_no` as I don't think the actual total would equal the `rows.length` value.

Comment: Works well also with rows that are set in a jQuery object such $(rows)